# How to add new elements to an objects-array using event listener and show it on the html page (edited code)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, dom

(I posted this question before but there was a missing element i forgot to add so people thought that was the problem but it is not actually so i'm posting again with the correct code that i should have used first)

I was trying to make a **todo application**, then I wanted to add new todo using a `form` and an `event listener` but, when I finished the code the app only adds the written text to the `object-array` and doesn't actually add it to the todos list in the html page.

I'll provide a small code down below showing the array, the setup code and the html as well in order to make this question short, but if you want to see the whole application code feel free to check this github's repository: https://github.com/salahmak/Todo-application

You can also check out the live version of the app from this `ngrok` link (i'll keep it live until I fix the problem) : http://7eb95c9a.ngrok.io

The code:

```js
// The array
const todos = [{
  text: 'wake up',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'get some food',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'play csgo',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'play minecraft',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'learn javascript',
  completed: false
}];


//creating p elements and assigning their text content to each "text" property of the "todos" array

todos.forEach(function(todo) {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = todo.text;
  document.querySelector('#todo').appendChild(p);
})
```

```html
<h1>Todos</h1>
<div id="todo"></div>
<form id="form">
  Add a new todo
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type your first name" name="firstName">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you add the code of adding the `todo` when you submit the form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (update the DOM after adding an element):

```
 document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let newObject = { text: e.target.elements.firstName.value, completed: false };
      todos.push(newObject);
      renderTodos(todos, filters);
    });
```

Here is the full fiddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/9j2nky6q/

Comment: OH how didnt i think of that
it actually worked lol thanks man

Answer (score 1):

```js
// The array
const todos = [{
  text: 'wake up',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'get some food',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'play csgo',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'play minecraft',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'learn javascript',
  completed: false
}];


//creating p elements and assigning their text content to each "text" property of the "todos" array

todos.forEach(function(todo) {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = todo.text;
  document.querySelector('#todo').appendChild(p);
})

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var todo = document.querySelector('input').value;
  todos.push({
    text: todo,
    completed: false
  });   document.querySelector('#todo').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>' + todo + '</p>');
});
```

```html
<h1>Todos</h1>
<div id="todo"></div>
<form id="form">
  Add a new todo
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type your first name" name="firstName">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the anwser looks a lil bit long and has some stuff that i don't know yet however it should work

Comment: It's just a mockup to clarify the raw process. In fact I just added the event listener. Feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you explain the last line ? which contains this method: .insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: `insertAdjacentHTML` is an equivalent to `append`. The difference is it inserts a `string` as markup (not a node). In this case `<p>` and a variable `todo` which is the value of the `input` field. Well documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).